# OCaml Counting if char exists in char list : syntax error

Tags: ocaml

```
let count (l: char list) : bool =
  let cnt = 0 in
  let rec check l =
    match l with
    | [] -> false
    | h::t -> if h = 'a' then 
  let cnt + 1
  check t
  else check t
  in check []
;;
```

what causes the syntax error?

I want to add 1 if 'a' exists and -1 if 'b' exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write it like this :

```ml
let rec count l =
  match l with
  | [] -> 0
  | c::t -> if c = 'a' then 1 + count t else count t
```

But this isn't tail recursive. To make it tail recursive, you'll have to add an accumulator and write an auxiliary function:

```ml
let count l =
  let rec aux cnt l =
    match l with
    | [] -> cnt
    | c::t -> if c = 'a' then aux (cnt + 1) t else aux cnt t
  in
  aux 0 l
```

Now this is tail recursive but a little bit long to write, so you could just use List.fold_left and still have a tail recursive function:

```ml
let count l =
  List.fold_left (fun cnt c -> if c = 'a' then cnt + 1 else cnt) 0 l
```

Comment: all of your examples cause a syntax error... is it because I have a boolean in my function? what do I need to do if I want to return boolean

Comment: @user11398251 What exactly are you trying to do? Returning a boolean value makes no sense if you're trying to count the number of occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

OCaml is a functional language, variables are immutable (their content might be mutable, but that is not the default).
Consequently,

```
let cnt + 1
```

is both a syntax error and a logical error: it is not possible to update `cnt` in such way.
As a first step, I would suggest to write a recursive version of count (and maybe rename it to `exists_a`) without using `if`s :

```ml
let rec count l = match l with
| [] -> ...
| 'a' :: t -> ...
| _ :: t -> ...
```